# How can I put all my JButtons towards the end of my Frame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

```
                JButton addbutton1 = new JButton("Sorting");
                JPanel wrap = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,100, 5));  
                wrap.add(sortingbtn);  
                framing.add(wrap, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

All buttons show up apart from the button above stated wrap which I'm trying to figure out [buttons shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YNMS.png). The hgap and vgap on the buttons that are displayed are all 100 , 5 but I'm not sure why the sort button isn't displaying when I add it.

I can see that the first button variables all match , however the rest all have wrap.add which does display the other buttons.

Comment: 1) Why are you creating new JPanels every time when you don't use them? 2) You don't need to add `wrapper2` to your `frame` everytime something new was added. Simply do it once after all the buttons are added to the panel. 3) There is no `sortbtn` reated anywhere, you create `clearbtn` twice, that's why the "Sort" button is never added. This should not even compile IMO.

Comment: Hi, It does compile , I have got these buttons working

Comment: I accidentally made a mistake in the question , there was a sortbtn orginally

Comment: Call `frame.pack()` at the end, before making the frame visible. This will layout your components correctly and size the frame accordingly.

Comment: (1-) **Troll alert**. This OP has asked 5 related questions on this topic using 3 different userids over the last week and he keeps deleting the old questions to remove all evidence. He has been asked multiple time to post a proper [mre] to demonstatre the problem. He has been given a link to the Swing tutorial on using layout managers and has been asked to use the demo code as the basis for his code to be structured properly. All suggestion given are ignored. As you can see once again 4 random lines of code are posted and he expects us to fix the problem.

Comment: @camickr interesting and good to know what he is up to. But check the edit-history, there were more than 4 lines of code there at the beginnning. Not sure why he then removed those.

Comment: @maloomeister, even more than 4, it is still not a valid [mre]. He has been given working examples to his question showing how to write an "MRE". For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788431/how-can-i-overwrite-added-numbers-onto-text-area-then-display-all-at-once was asked under a different id. It demonstrates how to display buttons at the top. Moving them to the bottom is a simple change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make your code simple just as below and you need to call the `pack()` method of frame to see all added components:

`note:`  you don't to repeat this: `frame.add(wrapper2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);` each time for adding new component to the `JPanel`. so one time is enough.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JButton addbtn = new JButton("Add");

JPanel wrap = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 100, 5));
wrap.add(addbtn); // adding the button
JButton displaybtn = new JButton("Display");
wrap.add(displaybtn);
JButton clearbtn = new JButton("Clear");
wrap.add(clearbtn);
JButton sortbtn = new JButton("Sort");
wrap.add(sortbtn);

frame.add(wrapper2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: Superb , I just had to resize!

Comment: the better solution is to call the `pack()` method of frame to view all the added components when the frame becomes **visible**.